# mysql insert into function

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, dml

I am creating a simple PHP webpage with MySQL database.
The MYSQL database have the following contents: (illustration on left)
I just want to know  a possible way of doing some Data Manipulation to achieve the results on the right portion below.

```
 (initial value)                                                 (final result)

    ID | MINUS '1'(to "next" ID's)                ID |               ID |

     1 |   0                                       1 | ------------>  1 | 
     2 |   1 --> (will minus '1' to ID 3           2 | ------------>  2 | 
     3 |   0     up to the last)            3-1 =  2 | ------------>  2 | 
     4 |   0                                4-1 =  3 | ------------>  3 | 
     5 |   1 --> (minus '1' AGAIN to ID 6   5-1 =  4 | ------------>  4 | 
     6 |   0      up to the last)           6-1 =  5      -1    --->  4 | 
     7 |   0                                7-1 =  6      -1    --->  5 |
```

It is just COUNTING the number of minus and then subtracting it to ALL the ID that follows it.  ID 2 has tells the next ID, which is 3 to subtract 1 to itself up to the last ID, (3-1 , 4-1, 5-1, 6-1, 7-1 ) but another instance came. ID 5 tells ID 6 to subtract itself again up to the last, so MINUS 2 from ID 6 up to the last ID. from just 6-1, 7-1 ---> 6-2, 7-2.

I know it sounds very easy for you, but I'm just a newbie and find this thing hard. Sorry for the headache. Hope someone helps, Thanks!

my DML is like (just for illustration, this should be in php, I will convert it, just help me in the LOGIC)

```
for($x=0;$x<num_rows;$x++)
   {

   if(MINUS = 1){
      query(UPDATE table_name SET ID=ID-1 WHERE ID = $x);}
    }
```

Something like that, i am still a newbie in decision making loops. I will be grateful if you could fix my loop. I am new to this community, I beg for your understanding.

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried so far? It would be easier for us to help you if we know what you've tried.

Comment: I had just updated it, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL either using variables or standard SQL.  Here is the standard SQL:

```
select id, minus,
       (id - coalesce((select sum(minus) from table t2 where t2.id < t.id), 0)) as newId
from table t;
```

Here is the variable version:

```
select id, minus,
       (id - minus + (@value := @value + minus)) as newId
from table t cross join
     (select @value = 0) const
order by id
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. May I ask what is the 'value' you are referring in select id, value. I know its a very noob question, sorry

Comment: the 'id' and 'value' is what will be returned when the sql query is finished running. I think Gordon meant to use minus in there, so change it to 'minus' and give it a shot

Comment: Sorry for the hassle, but i really can't fully get your answer. Don't get me wrong, Its My bad, I am a newbie. Could you just explain a little bit further. What are you referring as "value" and "t2.id" and "t.id"? Kindly, Please help

Comment: @aashnisshah ok, ill give it a try. Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: @aashnisshah i'm stuck, where or how should I get that value? should I initialize it, get it from something e.g row?

Comment: There isn't enough space here for me to elaborate code - I'll submit an answer. Give me a minute

Comment: @user3425991 . . . Sorry about that.  I misread the name of the column.  I intended `minus` based on a closer reading of the question.  `id` and `minus` are the two columns in the table.

Comment: @aashnisshah please take your time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, i had a bad question. sorry

Comment: @GordonLinoff is t2.id and t.id different?

Comment: Yup, t2.id refers to a second instance of the table from t.id

Comment: @GordonLinoff i mean are you referring to two tables t and t2? or is that a row or something.

Comment: @aashnisshah i'm going crazy over this, could I test the statndart SQL directly? cause I'm using MySQL Query Browser.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hands down, you saved my day. A lot of thanks dude.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sir, last question. can I persist this changes to the column name 'id'. I mean the new values will replace the old ones.   column ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ---> 1,2,2,3,4,4,5. something like update values set? some way like that?

Comment: @aashnisshah hello again, I greatly appreciate your help yesterday. If you have time this is my last question. can I persist this changes to the column name 'id'. I mean the new values will replace the old ones. column ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ---> 1,2,2,3,4,4,5. something like update values set? some way like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL implementation as follows:

```
select id, minus,
   (id - coalesce((select sum(minus) from table t2 where t2.id < t.id), 0)) as newId
```

from table t;

The code idea came from Gordon's post, here is an elaboration.

The first part is `select` which states that you want to select certain input from mysql. `id, minus` follows, and means that you want to return the values of `id` and `minus` when the query has finished running.

The rest of it falls under the third part, where you perform the subtraction, and return the value of the subtraction as newId. So when the sql returns, it will get a row with ID, MINUS and NEWID as it's headings.

The subtraction works like this: coalesce returns the first non-null value (i.e. `1`) in the list. the `table t2` is using a second version of the table and calling it t2 so that you can compare information.

I hope this clarified things for you!

Comment: 2. could I test the standard SQL directly? cause I'm using MySQL Query Browser

Comment: im giving you headache but please dont get mad, what is the difference of t2 and t? how should i put it a query browser.

Comment: i mean how should I query t2, how could i make t2 refer to the second version of table?

Comment: Kindly answer it. take your time always

Comment: thanks for the response again. i mean how should I query t2, how could i make t2 refer to the second version of table? Thanks you for all your help. Hope you answer again. I'll be back tomorrow and I'll update you asap. Thanks for the time, Good night.

Comment: MySQL commands do it automatically - you don't need to give it any variables

Comment: i see. thank you sir, i'll update you tomorrow. thanks for your patience and understanding.

Comment: hello again, I greatly appreciate your help yesterday. If you have time this is my last question. can I persist this changes to the column name 'id'. I mean the new values will replace the old ones. column ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ---> 1,2,2,3,4,4,5. something like update values set? some way like that

Comment: hello again, I greatly appreciate your help yesterday. If you have time this is my last question. can I persist this changes to the column name 'id'. I mean the new values will replace the old ones. column ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ---> 1,2,2,3,4,4,5. something like update values set? some way like that

Comment: hello again, I greatly appreciate your help yesterday. If you have time this is my last question. can I persist this changes to the column name 'id'. I mean the new values will replace the old ones. column ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ---> 1,2,2,3,4,4,5. something like update values set? some way like that